# Sum Nested Template Parameters at Compile Time

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm looking for a better way to calculate the sum of numeric template parameters associated with nested template classes. I have a working solution here, but I want to do this **without** having to create this extra helper template class `DepthCalculator` and partial specialization `DepthCalculator<double,N>`:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T,size_t N>
struct DepthCalculator
{
  static constexpr size_t Calculate()
  {
    return N + T::Depth();
  }
};

template<size_t N>
struct DepthCalculator<double,N>
{
  static constexpr size_t Calculate()
  {
    return N;
  }
};

template<typename T,size_t N>
class A
{
  std::array<T,N> arr;
public:
  static constexpr size_t Depth()
  {
    return DepthCalculator<T,N>::Calculate();
  }
  // ...
  // Too many methods in A to write a separate specialization for.
};

int main()
{
  using U = A<A<A<double,3>,4>,5>;
  U x;
  constexpr size_t Depth = U::Depth(); // 3 + 4 + 5 = 12
  std::cout << "Depth is " << Depth << std::endl;
  A<double,Depth> y;
  // Do stuff with x and y
  return 0;
}
```

The static function `A::Depth()` returns the proper depth at compile time, which can then be used as a parameter to create other instances of `A`. It just seems like a messy hack to have to create both the `DepthCalculator` template and a specialization just for this purpose.

I know I can also create a specialization of A itself with a different definition of `Depth()`, but this is even more messy due to the number of methods in `A`, most of which depend on the template parameters. Another alternative is to inherit from A and then specialize the child classes, but this also seems overly complicated for something that seems should be simpler.

Are there any cleaner solutions using C++11?

---

**Summary Edit**

In the end, this is the solution I went with in my working project:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T,size_t N>
class A
{
  std::array<T,N> arr;

  template<typename U>
  struct Get { };
  template<size_t M>
  struct Get<A<double,M>> { static constexpr size_t Depth() { return M; } };
  template<typename U,size_t M>
  struct Get<A<U,M>>
    { static constexpr size_t Depth() { return M + Get<U>::Depth(); } };

public:
  static constexpr size_t GetDepth()
  {
    return Get<A<T,N>>::Depth();
  }
  // ...
  // Too many methods in A to write a separate specialization for.
};

int main()
{
  using U = A<A<A<double,3>,4>,5>;
  U x;
  constexpr size_t Depth = U::GetDepth(); // 3 + 4 + 5 = 12
  std::cout << "Depth is " << Depth << std::endl;
  A<double,Depth> y;
  // Do stuff with x and y
  return 0;
}
```

Nir Friedman made some good points about why `GetDepth()` should be an external function, however in this case there are other `Get` functions (not shown) which are appropriately member functions, and therefore it would make the most sense to have `GetDepth()` a member function too. I also borrowed Nir's idea of having the `Depth()` functions only call themselves, rather than `GetDepth()` which creates a bit less circular dependencies.

I chose skypjack's answer because it most directly provided what I had originally asked for.

Comment: Is [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0227a8a57c734d88) fine?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki That is an interesting approach, thank you. I'll sit on this for a bit and see what else comes up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said:

> I want to do this without having to create this extra helper template class `DepthCalculator`

So, maybe this one (minimal, working example) is fine for you:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<cassert>

template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct S {
    template<class U, std::size_t M>
    static constexpr
    typename std::enable_if<not std::is_arithmetic<U>::value, std::size_t>::type
    calc() {
        return M+U::calc();
    }

    template<typename U, std::size_t M>
    static constexpr
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<U>::value, std::size_t>::type
    calc() {
        return M;
    }

    static constexpr std::size_t calc() {
        return calc<T, N>();
    }
};

int main() {
    using U = S<S<S<double,3>,4>,5>;
    static_assert(U::calc() == 12, "oops");
    constexpr std::size_t d = U::calc();
    assert(d == 12);
}
```

I'm not sure I got exactly your problem.
Hoping this can help.

If you are with C++14, you can use also:

```
template<class U, std::size_t M>
static constexpr
std::enable_if_t<not std::is_arithmetic<U>::value, std::size_t>
```

If you are with C++17, it becomes:

```
template<class U, std::size_t M>
static constexpr
std::enable_if_t<not std::is_arithmetic_v<U>, std::size_t>
```

The same applies to the other *sfinae*d return type.

Comment: Yes, this is along the lines of what I was looking for and had previously tried to do. If you don't mind I'll wait for a bit before selecting an answer, but so far I like this one the best.

Comment: I don't mind, it's up to you to accept an answer. I'm here to help if possible, that's all. ;-)

Comment: Also, if I can suggest you, you can even start a bounty if your goal is to catch attention for the question so as to explore different solutions. More users interested in your question means more answers, maybe it's worth it.

Comment: This only really differs from the OP's solution in simply making the helper struct nested, and in using enable_if, which is more complex, and in particular using enable_if in the return type of the function (instead of in a defaulted template parameter) which obscures the signature of the function and therefore the code.

Comment: As he mentioned in the comments, this is what he tried and failed to do and that's why he likes it. What's wrong exactly with giving him what he wants?

Comment: Well, partly I just found it amusing that you were so critical about similarities in my answer to other answers, when really all the answers on this page are quite similar to each other and the OP. Also, I'm starting to feel that this is an X-Y problem, as there's zero reason to make calc a member in the first place.

Comment: Criticisms are fine, you shouldn't be upset for them indeed. My two cents.

Comment: @NirFriedman "there's zero reason to make calc a member in the first place" Encapsulation? My goal is to keep all the functionality contained in one class and not pollute the namespace with ancillary functions or classes. This answer does this in the most direct way, in my opinion.

Comment: @Matt its hardly polluting the namespace to put useful functions in it. A couple of relevant pieces: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197, http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm. In Herb Sutter's words: "Always make it a member if it has to be one... Prefer to make it a member if it needs access to internals... In all other cases, prefer to make it a nonmember nonfriend." Making things members that don't need to be members actually *weakens* encapsulation, because it increases the surface area of your object to no advantage.

Comment: @NirFriedman I see your point here, and quite honestly it's made me re-examine my reasons for putting this function in the class when it doesn't have to be - perhaps it is better that something like this merely go in the same namespace as you have been advocating. I'll think about it more but in any case I'll probably select a solution that satisfies my original question/requirements. I do appreciate you sharing this alternative viewpoint.

Comment: @Matt fair enough, glad you found it interesting.

Answer (score 2):

#### Option #1

Redefine your trait as follows:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T>
struct DepthCalculator
{
    static constexpr std::size_t Calculate()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

template <template <typename, std::size_t> class C, typename T, std::size_t N>
struct DepthCalculator<C<T,N>>
{
    static constexpr size_t Calculate()
    {
        return N + DepthCalculator<T>::Calculate();
    }
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class A
{
public:
    static constexpr size_t Depth()
    {
        return DepthCalculator<A>::Calculate();
    }

private:
    std::array<T,N> arr;
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/acf52942b1d17828)

#### Option #2

Change the trait into function overloads:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

namespace DepthCalculator
{
    template <typename T> struct tag {};

    template <template <typename, std::size_t> class C, typename T, std::size_t N>
    static constexpr size_t Compute(tag<C<T,N>>)
    {
        return N + Compute(tag<T>{});
    }

    template <typename T>
    static constexpr size_t Compute(tag<T>)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class A
{
public:
    static constexpr std::size_t Depth()
    {
        return Compute(DepthCalculator::tag<A>{});
    }

private:    

    std::array<T,N> arr;
};
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a129c9108be960b)

Comment: Good one (as usual), but the OP asked for a solution that has not an external class. To match his requirements, you should at least refactor a bit.

Comment: @skypjack a solution without an external class was proposed and provided at the very beginning in my comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777189/sum-nested-template-parameters-at-compile-time/36778736?noredirect=1#comment61133153_36777189). example 2 is its more versatile counterpart

Comment: Oops, my fault, I didn't see the link in the comments, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this wholly non-intrusively, which I think is advantageous:

```
template <class T>
struct Depth
{
    constexpr static std::size_t Calculate()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

template <class T, std::size_t N>
struct Depth<A<T, N>>
{
    constexpr static std::size_t Calculate()
    {
        return N + Depth<T>::Calculate();
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
using U = A<A<A<double,3>,4>,5>;
constexpr size_t depth = Depth<U>::Calculate(); // 3 + 4 + 5 = 12
```

I realize your original question was how to do this without the extra "helper template", which my solution still has. But on the flip side, it's moved the functionality completely out of `A` itself, so its not really a helper template any more, it's just a template. This is pretty short, doesn't have any template template parameters unlike Piotr's solutions, is easy to extend with other classes, etc.

Comment: *"(...) doesn't have any template template parameters"* and this is the advantage that makes your solution better? apart for that, this is just a copy-paste

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki So aside from how it's different, it's the same? Insightful. I wrote this solution when I read the question, then I saw your answer. I compared, I decided that there were a couple sufficiently significant differences for it to be worth posting. Template template parameters are pretty heavy duty things, avoiding one when it's totally unnecessary is a reasonable advantage.

Comment: you know what I mean, this the same solution, but constrained to `A` instead of all class templates of the form `<T,N>`, and you claim that it's somehow different and better, since it allows for... specialization? funny

Comment: I'm with Piotr, sorry, this is the same solution with a bit of sintactic sugar. Moreover, what you mentioned as *features* are arguable at least. My two cents.

Comment: @skypjack You don't have to apologize. All solutions will be pretty similar, that's just the nature of the question. Intrusiveness is not arguable; it's well known in C++ that free functions should be preferred by default because it reduces coupling, improves encapsulation, etc. What exactly is the benefit to making it a static member? Similarly, simplicity is a benefit; I don't see what benefit the template template parameter gives you. It differs in behavior that the user did not specify in either direction.